# what is the fundamental difference between node, host and gateway?

Tags: router, network

I want to know what is the node and host in the network in some books say that node is computer or router so this computer is a normal computer?  And if was a router why called node in the network which I knew that host means (www) or (FTP) in gateway I don't understand what does it?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the linked answer above, a gateway is a router (therefore also a node) that is the next-hop address for hosts on a network subnet.  Hosts generally don't have any routing information, so when they determine that a packet's destination address is not on the local subnet, they forward it to the gateway address, which usually is a router that can forward the packet.  The router is a "gateway to the rest of the network."